# Is it safe to use a laptop with a dropped screw somewhere in the motherboard?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, electric-shock, screws

I had to completely disassemble a laptop to get at the hard drive. While I was taking the screws out, I dropped one into the closed part of the laptop that can't be accessed. The screw is floating somewhere in the motherboard now. I am actually using the laptop right now and nothing seems to be wrong, but I am afraid to leave the laptop on and unattended because I am afraid that it could start a fire or something.

Are these concerns legitimate? Should I keep turning off my laptop whenever I leave it unattended? What is the worst that could happen? What dangers should I be aware of?

Comment: That seemed more like, "is it safe to service a computer while it is on?", not "is it safe to keep it unattended if I can't get the screw out?".

Comment: Ok, but the answer is the same :)  Get the screw out.  A short is not a good thing.  A fire is unlikely, but causing at a minimum crashes and at worst permanent damage to the laptop, is quite possible.

Comment: @Madball73 if you're not going to explain how it can cause crashes and or permanent damage then your comment is not very uesful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A loose piece of conductive metal in a device is a cause for concern, even more so when the device is designed to be picked up and transported. The ideal case would be that it would become lodged in a non-harmful location, perhaps by being attracted by a magnet.

The less damaging options would include the screw shorting traces on a board that cause no permanent damage, followed by shorts that could cause damage.

The more dangerous options include fire. While modern laptops are unlikely to have wall socket power inside their enclosures there is no guarantee that the screw could not manage to find its way to a place where it could short either wires or traces coming from the battery. If that happens it could cause the battery to [catch fire](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/lithium_ion_safety_concerns).

Given the risk I'd encourage you to either remove the loose screw or have it removed if the disassembly required to retrieve it is beyond your comfort level.

Answer (score -5):

I'm sure it won't cause anything dangerous to happen in terms of electricity. That question is for electronics.stackexchange.  What can cause a fire is if a battery is faulty and goes on fire when it overcharges, though that is rare with laptop batteries - more common with toys from china with cheap rechargable batteries and no regulations. And nothing to do with a screw being in there.  I'd guess that the worst damage a screw could cause is the screw goes in a fan you hear the fan struggle, this happens repeatedly many many times, the fan dies sooner than it would, and then the CPU overheats..i've never heard of a CPU going on fire.

I once had a motherboard whose installations instructions said insert a screw here, but there was a flaw with the motherboard or instructions, and a screw there shorted it, so solution was not to put a screw in that hole(the mbrd retailer saw it as a flaw in the instructions). But it didn't break the motherboard. It just caused it to not start up while it was shorted. If you can win anything then you should bet your house that your laptop won't catch fire from a screw being in there.

Fans sometimes die on laptops, the case can get hot and the processor could get very hot but even that doesn't cause them to go on fire.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this. You are right, 99 times out of a hundred that this would not damage the motherboard or psu, but in the case of that hundredth time, it can conceivably damage the electronics. Even a little damage to a single pathway on the PCB can result in odd apparently random crashes and freezes that will almost certainly never be diagnosed correctly, so I'm not inclined to accept anecdotal evidence, on this one.

Comment: @FrankThomas well, maybe a good one for electronics.stackexchange  cos  they may have seen portable electronic devices with something metal loose, and diagnosed it correctly, and if it did cause that, they might know.  If not, then even saying 1% of the time might be a big over-estimate.  Remember that a laptop screw is as light as a feather not like a screwdriver